# SQLITE connection using Harp

Tags: javascript, sqlite, pug, harp

i have a page which is in jade,i have a validation form in that page.I am using JavaScript to validate.i wanted to know can we connect to sqlite and extract those data's.
thanking you in advance

Comment: Without some tags for "Harp" or "jade" or whatever it is you're using, nobody will find your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Harp is a STATIC webserver. It is not intended to have any backend code to handle anything the user submits. The only things harp gives you is pre-processing when generating the page that is served.

If you intend to build a dynamic web app and serve it using a static server such as Harp, you'll need to use a 3rd party 'Backend as a Service' offering such as GoInstant or Firebase.

Comment: Thank you so much. your suggestions are very helpful. i will surely follow tat.

Answer (score 1):

As z5h mentioned, Harp is a static web server so it doesn’t have something like this built-in, but using a backend as a service like Firebase is a great option.

There are lots of other options, too. If you’re looking to do something fairly involved, I you could use Harp as middleware for an express app that connects to sqlite, for example.

Depending on the complexity of the form you’re creating, you could also attempt the solution client-side. In the past, I’ve used [Wufoo](http://wufoo.com), or Google Docs forms and retrieved the data with [Tabeletop](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop). If you’re just making a simple form, this might be the best option, but it totally depends on the context.